# Why does my laptop screen occasionally flicker?

Tags: laptop-display

I use an Asus Ultrabook UX301L with Windows 8.1. Everything works except sometimes very short moments the screen flickers and just once. Then it can take hours or days until I see it flicker again. When it flickers I didn't do anything, e.g. just reading a PDF document with no interaction. Do you know what the reason could be and if so, what can be done about it?

Comment: The internal cable which connects your GPU to the LCD could be loose. It's definitely not a tough VGA connector with screw-pins. Just look how frail this thing is: http://www.sparepartswarehouse.com/LCD-Removal/images/LCDScreenRemoval/DetailPhotos/VideoCable2.jpg and FWIW desktop iMacs use the same style connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be two possibility first one is that the cpu and screen connectivity and other may be the driver I have the same problem with my acer laptop then the customer executive told that change the os or update driver and adjust the refresh rate as best suited to yuor machine.

I hope this help.